# How to let Org-mode open a link like [[file://file.org]] in current window instead of default in other window?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I hope to use `[C-c C-o]` to open a link like `[[file://filename.org|filename]]` in current window, instead of the default in other window.

How to change this Org-mode default behavior ?

Seems default `[C-u C-c C-o]` is force open link in other window.

And there is a similar question at here: [How do I keep Emacs org-mode from splitting windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854214/how-do-i-keep-emacs-org-mode-from-splitting-windows?rq=1)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to change the value of `org-link-frame-setup`.  Default value contains the cons `(file . find-file-other-window)`.  You may replace it by `(file . find-file)`.

Comment: I replace it with `(file . find-file)`, but soon I found `[C-u C-c C-o]` open link at point in current window *too*. I hope to keep `[C-u C-c C-o]` to open link in other window.  I do not know how to do this. I readed the docstring of the variable `org-link-frame-setup`. Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: If you want different commands for opening links using different frame setup policies, you may create them by doing `(let ((org-link-frame-setup whatever-policies)) (org-open-at-point))`, and then bind it to the key combo of your choice.

Comment: Here is how you update the value of `org-link-frame-setup`: `(add-to-list 'org-link-frame-setup '(file . find-file))`

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution I wrote, inspired by the answer of @juanleon. It maps `C-c C-o` to open the link in the current window, but leaves the default behaviour for `C-u C-c C-o` (open in other window). It does so without breaking the universal argument function (which happens for me when I naively remap `C-u C-c C-o`).

```
(defun org-force-open-current-window ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((org-link-frame-setup (quote
                               ((vm . vm-visit-folder)
                                (vm-imap . vm-visit-imap-folder)
                                (gnus . gnus)
                                (file . find-file)
                                (wl . wl)))
                              ))
    (org-open-at-point)))
;; Depending on universal argument try opening link
(defun org-open-maybe (&optional arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (if arg
      (org-open-at-point)
    (org-force-open-current-window)
    )
  )
;; Redefine file opening without clobbering universal argumnet
(define-key org-mode-map "\C-c\C-o" 'org-open-maybe)
```