# org mode - clickable text jump to specific line in emacs

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have a file list and wish to jump to specific line if click the text.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output

for i in range(0,10):
    print "[[./test%d.txt:100]]"%i

#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
#+begin_example
[[./test0.txt:100]]
[[./test1.txt:100]]
[[./test2.txt:100]]
[[./test3.txt:100]]
[[./test4.txt:100]]
[[./test5.txt:100]]
[[./test6.txt:100]]
[[./test7.txt:100]]
[[./test8.txt:100]]
[[./test9.txt:100]]
#+end_example
```

If without the linenumber at the end, click the text line will open the file but not jump to the specific line number.

How should I change the syntax to jump to line number?

Comment: Just replace : with :: before line number, for instance [[./test0.txt::100]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, the only problem was the syntax for [Org external links](http://orgmode.org/manual/External-links.html). It is

```
[[./test%d.txt::100]] (and not [[./test%d.txt:100]])
```

This will work in your Emacs Org buffer, however the link will not be exported if you publish your file (C-c C-e h o).

If you also want to export/publish your links you can use:

```
#+OPTIONS: d:t \n:t

#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output drawer :exports both

for i in range(0,10):
    print "[[./test%d.txt::100][test%d.txt::100]]" %(i,i)

#+END_SRC
```

The **d:t** option tells to export drawers, the **\n:t** one to preserve linebreaks.

Putting your python code result into a drawer (the :results output drawer) allows org mode to interpret it as true org-mode code.

Comment: Great, but when I click the links one by one, emacs will open a new window if I didn't close the previous one. Can I make emacs to reuse the the window then no need to close previous window?

Comment: @beetlej you mean emacs buffer or web browser once that org mode file has been exported? (in both cases I currently have no answer but I can try to have a look)

Comment: Now I am talking about emacs. Thanks.

Comment: I just found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590784/how-to-let-org-mode-open-a-link-like-file-file-org-in-current-window-inste that seems to work: see answer#2 and custumize the org-link-frame-setup value to find-file as explained... Does it solved your problem?

Comment: @beetlej I answered but forgot to mention you, sorry